# using some technique to fix the url

Tags: regex, coldfusion

i am getting a `url` from `cfhttp` page request as:

```
<a href="http://subdomian.maindomain.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.rs.com ')">http://www.rs.com</a>
```

i am trying to replace it as:

```
<a href="http://www.rs.com" target="_blank">http://www.rs.com</a>
```

the rs.cfm is gonna be dynamic everytime, it can be `sb,sd,ge` etc etc

and i want to add a target to the a href

trying it like this

```
<cfset lnk = replace(cfhttp.filecontent,'subdomian.maindomain.com/http://www.al.com/','http://www.al.com/','ALL')>
```

this works in one case where the name is `al`, but do not add the **target** attribute to it. also

Comment: Check out jSoup, it is perfectly suited to this type of manipulation.

Comment: yes, but i need to use regex, any idea on that,

Comment: Tag your question with `regex` too, it will let `regex` guys provide you  the solution.

Comment: ok did that, but cf uses different engine for regex , apache roi

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.  *NOTE: I have not tested this code. I will leave that up to you.*

Your beginning string is:

```
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.rs.com ')
```

You can remove the beginning part by doing something like the following:

```
<cfset lnk = "http://subdomain.maindomain.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.rs.com ')">
<cfset lnk = ReplaceNoCase(lnk,"http://subdomain.maindomain.com/javascript:popOne('")>
```

This should leave `lnk` set to the following:

```
http://www.rs.com ')
```

Now you need to remove the trailing part like so:

```
<cfset lnk = ReplaceNoCase(lnk," ')")>  <!--- remove the space as well --->
```

Which should leave you with the URL that you want:

```
http://www.rs.com
```

Now just create your HTML output as desired:

```
<cfoutput>
<a href="#lnk#" target="_blank">#lnk#</a>
</cfoutput>
```

**This sample code assumes that the strings like `subdomain.maindomain.com ...` do not change.** If the string is dynamic then this code will not work and will need to be modified to possibly use a regex instead.

Putting it all together:

```
<cfset lnk = "http://subdomain.maindomain.com/javascript:popOne('http://www.rs.com ')">
<cfset lnk = ReplaceNoCase(lnk,"http://subdomain.maindomain.com/javascript:popOne('")>
<cfset lnk = ReplaceNoCase(lnk," ')")>  <!--- remove the space as well --->

<cfoutput>
<a href="#lnk#" target="_blank">#lnk#</a>
</cfoutput>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function :

```
 <cffunction name="convertLink">
    <cfargument name="siteLink" required="true" type="string">
    <cfset extractedLink = listGetAt(replace(replace(arguments.siteLink, "('", "||", "all"), "')", "||", "all"), 2, "||")>
    <cfreturn '<a href="' & extractedLink & '" target="_blank">'& extractedLink & '</a>'>
</cffunction>
```